# IntelliSence completion with () - For Resharper user on vanilla Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio

Im a resharper user who has landed on VS 2012 express without r# loaded.
Basic VS intelliSense is working. Using ctrl-space i can do something like

```
Process.GetProcesses
```

but what about the method parenthesis ()

```
Process.GetProcesses()
```

is what I was hoping to achieve. Is this Resharper only ?

I have looked in tools=>Options=>Text Editor=>C# intellisense
but cant find an option to get completion working id like.
even entering (    doesnt add closing ).

[image: Options for intellisense]

**Is this a case of get over it ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im back on my machine now...

Looks like the feature is only a Resharper option

[image]